# How can I PGP decrypt an entire mbox?

Tags: email, gpg, thunderbird, pgp

Thunderbird cannot search PGP-encrypted emails. Hence, I was considering copying all my emails from IMAP to local storage, then decrypting them all locally, so that they are searchable. Is this possible?

Thunderbird stores email folders as a single mbox file. I attempted `gpg -d mbox_file`, but this only decrypted a single email, and then failed with an error as follows.

```
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=46)
gpg: decryption failed: Bad signature
gpg: packet(3) too short
```

N.B. the mbox also contains non-encrypted email. I could perhaps filter these out from within Thunderbird, but the solution would preferably deal with this elegantly.

Comment: What is wrong with using enigmail for thunderbird?

Comment: Thunderbird + Enigmail cannot search through PGP-encrypted emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2020 (sorry, I've no idea when this function was added) enigmail has a "decrypt to folder" option. (At the very bottom of the context menu.)

And you can select all messages in a folder, then use it to decrypt all messages in bulk.

(My search found your question as I'm wanting to do the opposite: take a directory of plain text messages and encrypt them all, such that enigmail is needed to read them.)

Answer (score 2):

I want to add that I have written a Python script for just this purpose. It supports mbox and Maildir and is called [mbdecrypt](https://gitlab.com/kenogo/mbdecrypt).